# Working out why an event is not fired

Tags: jquery

I have a draggable which is using over within a draggable :

But the event is not firing, it is part of a much larger jQuery file and it seems to work every time I add it to jsFiddle. Are there any debug tools/methodologies I can use to figure out why this event is not firing ?

```
    over: function(event, ui) {
     console.log('in over');
    }
```

Comment: are the draggable elements added dynamically after the dom is loaded?

Comment: @Daniel Ruf No their loaded the same time as the dom, I think your referring to binding the event ?

Comment: yes, using the .on() function of jquery 1.7

Comment: is the javascript code at the end of the website?

Comment: @DanielRuf No, at beginning. the issue for me is that the items I'm trying to fire the event when dropped are not sortable. But thanks for your help

Comment: try to put it at the end of the website,  well but this is another issue, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

in Firebug you can add a breakpoint, 
and you may console.log(ui) to see if the ui's value has changed